How to use the coulomb force equation in infinite linear charge?

A uniformly-distributed linear charge with a charge density $\rho$ located along the line $x=c, y=0$ is parallel to an uncharged conducting infinite cylinder described by the  equation $x^2+y^2=a^2$ ($a<c$). Find the force per unit length exerted on the linear charge.

With the mirroring method I calculated the equivalent infinite linear charge and the first thing that came to my mind after that is to use Coulomb force equation but i cant figure out how to continue the problem

This seems like a physics problem, so perhaps you should consult https://physics.stackexchange.com.

@SimonSMN True, but it will certainly be closed over there due to being a "homework-like question".
